# Change language of reCAPTCHA in WPForms -WordPress-

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I'm using WordPress 4.7.1 with WPForms to handle my website forms. I'm using an option to implement Google reCAPTCHA and I need the language to be other than English. I've seen that there are two ways to do this but I don't know where to implement these snippets among the several files of WPForms.

```
//javascript
var RecaptchaOptions = {
 lang : 'es',
};
//or
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es'></script>
```

Thanks for any guideline. Greetions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe late, but probably this could help somebody else.

```
/wp-content/plugins/wpforms-lite/includes/class-frontend.php
```

just add **hl=<yourNewlang>** to the google recaptcha url.

Tested w WPForms Lite Version 1.4.1.1

Cheers.